# same google Client id used for multiple android projects

Tags: android, google-signin

I want google login for multiple projects with same client ID that we created in google API console.Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not possible !

Comment: No, it is not possible because the package name is not same of multiple projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible because the package name is not same of multiple projects.